# Fail to boot from external SSD

Tags: windows, boot, ssd, windows-to-go

My laptop recently broke down due to some hardware problems related to the motherboard. To restore my working environment, I plugged out the SSD drive where the operating system is installed and connected it to another computer through a USB SSD hard drive adapter.
I first tried booting directly from it, but the boot process stuck. Then I tried adding this external operating system to the windows boot manager(the new computer has its own Windows installed), but it failed again with a blue screen:

```
Your PC/Device needs to be repaired
The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.
File: \Windows\System32\winload.efi
Error code: 0xc000000e
```

So I googled this error code for solutions and found [this post](http://woshub.com/windows-8-winload-efi-is-missing-or-damaged).
I then tried all solutions in it, including running automatic repairment, enabling legacy boot, disabling ELAM, running system file check, restoring ESP partition from Windows folder, rebuilding BCD and MBR using `bootrec`, and none of those solutions worked - They all ended up with the same blue screen code.
But the most wired thing is that **the system could always boot successfully on my broken laptop when the SSD is plugged in *its original slot***(though it has a hardware problem, it's intermittent, which means it still works fine sometimes). The reason I emphasized the condition "in its original slot" is that I've also tried attaching it through the USB adapter and booting, and it failed as well.
So, all my attempts lead to a ridiculous conclusion: **the system in this SSD drive seems to bind with that specific slot**.
So, may anyone explain what the hell is happening? Or provide some more solutions that I haven't tried yet?
Here is some additional information:

- Model of my broken laptop: Lenovo Legion Y7000 2019
- Operating System: Windows 10 Professional 21H1
- It's an M.2 NVMe SSD drive
- There's no problem with the SSD drive itself, I've performed a health check already.
- When using `bootrec` in safe mode, `/FixBoot` always failed with the message `Access denied`.
- BitLocker is disabled

---

Well, I've just learned that Windows has a feature related to such a scenario: **Windows To Go**.
So, is this feature enabled by default on a standard Windows system? Or there are some crucial differences between a portable Windows and a standard one, which might be the root cause of the problem I'm facing?
If that's the case, **is there any approach that could turn the Windows in my SSD into a Windows To Go Workspace**?

Comment: Most of the time the error you saw means "bad disk"  If not the disk, then try a recovery USB from the computer manufacturer. You can also try a bootable USB from the Media Creation Link.

Comment: @John I do have a recovery USB. But since my new computer has its own system, there's no need to use it. I did all recovery operations on this system. Besides, I'm very sure the SSD itself is fine

Comment: I think it it reasonable to suggest that the broken laptop corrupted the drive on its way out and there may be nothing left to recover (even if you are sure the SSD is good).

Comment: Does the file `\Windows\System32\winload.efi` exist on the disk and can be used (test by copying elsewhere)?

Comment: @harrymc Yeah, I've also compared it with the one from the system on my new computer, and they are completely the same.

Comment: @John Actually, as an external storage device, it works fine. There's no problem manipulating files in it, which indicates there's no problem with both the SSD drive and its file system.

Comment: The explanation might be that the boot includes references to disk & partition by numbers, so can't work elsewhere. You might need to use the disk as internal.

Comment: @harrymc This explanation seems reasonable. If that's the case, it should be found somewhere in Microsoft's documentation. I'd go for a search.